# iPhone says it's activated but no connection

Tags: iphone

I have been using my iPhone 10 for 3 years, and suddenly today, it keeps saying "iPhone is activated" and my cellular connection disappeared.

I only can connect to Wi-Fi.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried with another (known good) SIM card or contacted your provider?

Comment: Are you on Sprint? Strange goings-on there.